# How to generate a subtotal amount using the DOM

Tags: javascript, function, dom

i'm trying to generate a simple subtotal amount for a small shopping cart project and it does not seem like the function can see the input value

my input HTML is:
`<input id="valueTest1" type="text" value="0" data-price="10.99">`

and i just need simply the data-price to * the value entered and then show in my subtotal HTML (shown below)

`<div id="itemTotal1" class="subtotal-price">£0.00</div>`

here is my function..

```
function calculateSubTotal() {
    let subtotal = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= itemTotal1; i++) {

        itemID = document.getElementById('valueTest1');
        if (typeof itemID === 'undefined' || itemID === null) {
            alert("No such item - " + "valueTest1");
        } else {
            subtotal = subtotal + parseFloat(valueTest1.value) * parseFloat(itemID.getAttribute("data-price"));
        }

    }
    console.log(valueTest1.value)
    document.getElementById('itemTotal1').innerHTML = "£" + subtotal;
}
```

I can console.log the input (valueTest1.value) outside of the function and it shows 0 but when i try to console.log the input in the function i get nothing, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `parseFloat(valueTest1.value)` Do you mean `parseFloat(itemID.value)`?  If you provide your code as a runnable snippet you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: How and when are you calling the function?

Comment: what is `itemTotal1`?

Comment: Side note, you should probably scope the variables `i` and `itemID` using `let` and `const`, respectively.

Comment: @CalvinNunes the itemTotal1 is my section for the total amount of the item amount * price

Comment: @Teemu i'm calling the function as soon as the value in the input - valueTest1.value is entered but the function doesn't look like it can see anything entered

Comment: @ShrewdStyle is your section? but I mean, is it a number? a node? an array? If it is not a number the for loop will never run

Comment: @CalvinNunes it is a number which should be getting passed in, i have added a separate function in my code to increase the number using a button... maybe this is stopping it from seeing the value?
https://codepen.io/ShrewdStyle/project/editor/APmkPz

Comment: you never set or even initializate the variable `itemTotal1`

Comment: @CalvinNunes ahhhh thank you, i will sort that out now, makes sense why the function cannot see the input now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some changes to do on your HTML and JS files.
First, you could do something more "generic" to use, so you can reuse it on every `input` and `button`.

HTML:

```
<section id="shopping-cart">
    <div class="shopping-cart">
        <!-- <div class="title">
            Online Store
        </div> -->
        <div class="title">
            <ul>
                <li>Online Store</li>
                <li>Quantity</li>
                <li>Price</li>
                <li>Subtotal</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Product 1 -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="delete-btn"></span>
                <span class="like-btn"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="image">
                <img src="/img/shop/cup.webp" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <span>Cyberpunk 2077</span>
                <span>Coffee Mug</span>
                <span>Multi-color</span>
            </div>

            <div class="quantity">
                <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '-');" class="minus-btn">
                    <img src="/img/shop/minus-btn.png" alt="#">
                </button> <!-- Check the parameter values! -->
                <input id="valueTest1" type="text" value="0" data-price="10.99" onchange="calculateSubTotal(this);"> <!-- Calculate when the user inputs value -->
                <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '+');" class="plus-btn">
                    <img src="/img/shop/plus-btn.png" alt="#">
                </button> <!-- Check the parameter values! -->
            </div>

            <div id="itemPrice1" class="total-price">£10.99</div>
            <div id="itemTotal1" class="subtotal-price">£0.00</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Product 2 -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="delete-btn"></span>
                <span class="like-btn"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="image">
                <img src="/img/shop/t-shirt.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <span>Cyberpunk 2077</span>
                <span>T-Shirt</span>
                <span>Multi-color</span>
            </div>

            <div class="quantity">
                <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '-');" class="minus-btn">
                    <img src="/img/shop/minus-btn.png" alt="#">
                </button>
                <input id="valueTest2" type="text" value="0" data-price="15.99" onchange="calculateSubTotal(this);">
                <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '+');" class="plus-btn">
                    <img src="/img/shop/plus-btn.png" alt="#">
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="itemPrice2" class="total-price">£<span>15.99</span></div>
            <div id="itemTotal2" class="subtotal-price">£<span>0.00</span></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Product 3 -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="delete-btn"></span>
                <span class="like-btn"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="image">
                <img src="/img/shop/jacket1.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <span>Cyberpunk 2077</span>
                <span>Womens Jacket</span>
                <span>Dark</span>
            </div>

            <div class="quantity">
                <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '-');" class="minus-btn">
                    <img src="/img/shop/minus-btn.png" alt="#">
                </button>
                <input type="text" id="valueTest3" value="0" data-price="24.99" onchange="calculateSubTotal(this);">
                <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '+');" class="plus-btn">
                    <img src="/img/shop/plus-btn.png" alt="#">
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="itemPrice3" class="total-price">£<span>24.99</span></div>
            <div id="itemTotal3" class="subtotal-price">£<span>0.00</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
function Input_ChangeValue(trigger, operation) {
  let inputChange = trigger.parentElement.querySelector("input");

  if (inputChange != null) {
    let actualValue = parseInt(inputChange.value);
    let nextValue = 0;

    switch (operation) {
      case "-":
        nextValue = actualValue - 1;
        break;
      case "+":
        nextValue = actualValue + 1;
        break;
    }

    if (nextValue <= 0) nextValue = 0; //don't allow negative numbers

    inputChange.value = nextValue;

    calculateSubTotal(inputChange);
  }
}

function calculateSubTotal(inputElement) {

  let subTotalDiv = inputElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".subtotal-price");

  if (inputElement != null && subTotalDiv != null) {
    //input found
    let qty = parseFloat(inputElement.value);
    let price = parseFloat(inputElement.getAttribute("data-price"));
    let subtotal = qty * price;

    //for debugging
    console.log(subtotal);
    subTotalDiv.innerHTML = `£${subtotal}`;
  }
}
```

Still there are a couple of validations you should check, like `input`s accepting only numbers or the `Subtotal` column only showing the first 2 decimal places.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank for yeah that was definitely mixed up, however after i've corrected it my function still cannot see my HTML, the console is just empty when i try to console.log the itemID.value still

Comment: Well, if i omit your "for" clause, and use it directly, is giving me the value correctly. [Check it out](https://jsbin.com/zehadupili/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: ahhh i see you are right, here is my full setup in codepen... i think it must be something in my HTML?
https://codepen.io/ShrewdStyle/project/editor/APmkPz

Comment: yes that is my goal, i was going to do a separate function for each SubTotal

Comment: Well, there are a couple of things that could be better implemeted. You should change the way you change values from your buttons to something more "generic".The same thing can be said about your Subtotal calculation. I made a couple of changes to your HTML and JS. [Check it out](https://jsbin.com/cixuwijeko/edit?html,js,output). If this is what you were looking for, i can edit the answer, so you can accept it :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this help, i tried your original answer and i was missing the function which you added in the input onchange="calculateSubTotal()"
and it's now working,

I have just looked at your new post and it works even better than the original, i will have a coffee now and study this for a while, thank you again... is there a way to add people on StackOverflow?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is redundant here - you are multiplying a single value from an element with another value from the same element.

I would go with the easier to read and safer:

```
    <body>
    <script>
        function calculateSubTotal() {
            let subtotal = 0;
            let item = document.getElementById('valueTest1');
            let itemTotal = document.getElementById('itemTotal1');

            if (typeof item === 'undefined' || item === null) {
                alert("No such item - " + " valueTest1");
            }

            let itemCount = parseFloat(item.value);
            if (!isNaN(itemCount)) {
                let itemPrice = parseFloat(item.getAttribute('data-price'));

                if (!isNaN(itemPrice )) {
                    subtotal += itemCount * itemPrice;
                }
            }

            itemTotal1.innerHTML = "£" + subtotal;
        }
    </script>

    <input id="valueTest1" type="text" value="0" data-price="10.99" onblur="javascript:calculateSubTotal()">

    <div id="itemTotal1" class="subtotal-price">£0.00</div>
</body>
```